# Should I call CoInitialize in timer callback

Tags: c++, winapi, com

I have a single thread program which start with

CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED)

I use COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED, because some functions (ex. URLDownloadToFile) didn't work properly with COINIT_MULTITHREADED in Windows XP

and now I am researching a strange behavior in callback function from CreateTimerQueueTimer - COM objects didn't created.

So, should I do COM initialization in timer callback function or I just missed something in my code?

Update: I just simplify my code and I am sure that I have called CoInitializeEx before timer callback, but on second timer callback it looks like i didn't call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CoInitialize(Ex) must be called at least once per thread, per developer, say.

If you, as a developer, own a thread (or a process) you have to call it once per thread if you use COM in that thread.

If you're unsure it has been called before or not because you don't own a thread, you can call it. The return value will tell you if you're the first one to call it or not. In this case, you should also check the return value for the dreaded code RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE which basically you're doomed and should use your own thread for what you have to do.

And as stated in the comment, each CoInitialize call must be paired with a CoUninitialize.

Comment: You must call CoUninitialize before returning back to the thread pool. Leave the thread the way you found it.